# Intellij view all unpushed local commits

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm working on 2 computers, sometimes I commit changes and switch to other branches and therefore forget these local commits, is there a way in Intellij to allow me to view all unpushed commits, so I can check changes in different branches.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to see all unpushed commits of the current branch - just open Push dialog and it will list all commits that are not yet pushed.

However, the only way to find ALL unpushed commits is to check the references in the Log tab, as suggested earlier

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the **Version Control** pane, select the **Log** tab, and look for any occurrences where branch `abc` is ahead of `origin/abc`.

Comment: I had to filter on 'Branch:All' to display the unpushed commits.